# How to manipulate combox to disable the buttons?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

What I'm trying to do is to disable the button once I choose/select the value from the combo box. for instance, I have....

```
<select name ="">
<option> disable </option>
<option> enable </option>
</select>

<input type ="submit" name="go" />
```

So, once I choose disable it will be automatically disabled the button otherwise enable.

How I going to implement this one?
Can you give me any examples?

Comment: To be clear.  You want to disable the the submit button when the <select> option is selected as disable?  Or you want the select to only alllow you to select one time then disable re-selection?

Comment: No, all I wanted is to select/choose between disable and enable, once I choose disable it will be automatically disabled the button otherwise enable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add Id attribute for both dropdown and button and use Jquery in following way you will acheive your goal:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddl" name ="">
<option> disable </option>
<option> enable </option>
</select>

<input type ="submit" name="go" id="btn" />
```

```js
$('#ddl').change(function () {

  if($(this).val()=="disable"  ){

     $('#btn').attr('disabled','disabled');  
   } else{
     $('#btn').removeAttr('disabled');

     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="">
    <option>Disable</option>
    <option>Enable</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="go" />

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".yourDDLClass").change(function({
        if($(this).val() == "disable"){
            $('#btn').attr("disabled","disabled");
        }else{
            $(".yourbtnClass").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });

});
```